# Union 2 tables and set value based on source of data

Tags: sql, set, union

Trying to sort this out...

I need a query that will combine both tables into 1 which I have below...

```
select PersonId, PersonFirstName, PersonLastName
from dbo.Person
UNION 
SELECT AdminId as PersonsId, AdminFirstName as PersonsFirstName, AdminLastName as       PersonsLastName
from dbo.UserAdmins
```

I want to create a new column and assign a value for "Person" or "Admin" depending where the record came from. So if record 1-10 came from dbo.Person, the newcolumn will be filled in as "Person", and if the next 5 came from Admin the newcolumn will be filled in as "Admin".

This seems relatively simple, but not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add a new column with the value you want:

```
select PersonId
    , PersonFirstName
    , PersonLastName
    , 'Person' as yourColName
from dbo.Person
UNION ALL
SELECT AdminId as PersonsId
    , AdminFirstName as PersonsFirstName
    , AdminLastName as       PersonsLastName
    , 'Admin' as yourColName
from dbo.UserAdmins
```

Comment: +1, though you really should make it `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`. The rows from each subquery in the `UNION` are distinct by virtue of the source identifier literal: a simple `UNION` must order the results and de-dupe them to no effect. That extra overhead is removed with `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize it was this simple.